# ejabberd 16.04 archiving messages in mysql database

Tags: mysql, xmpp, chat, ejabberd, strophe

These are some of the key points of my **ejabberd.yml**

```
auth_method: odbc

##   MySQL server:

odbc_type: mysql
odbc_server: "localhost"
odbc_database: "chat"
odbc_username: "admin"
odbc_password: "admin"

## If you want to specify the port:
odbc_port: 3306


modules
...
mod_mam:
db_type: odbc
```

**Full ejabberd.yml**

```
###
###'           ejabberd configuration file
###
###

### The parameters used in this configuration file are explained in more detail
### in the ejabberd Installation and Operation Guide.
### Please consult the Guide in case of doubts, it is included with
### your copy of ejabberd, and is also available online at
### http://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/docs/

### The configuration file is written in YAML.
### Refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML for the brief description.
### However, ejabberd treats different literals as different types:
###
### - unquoted or single-quoted strings. They are called "atoms".
###   Example: dog, 'Jupiter', '3.14159', YELLOW
###
### - numeric literals. Example: 3, -45.0, .0
###
### - quoted or folded strings.
###   Examples of quoted string: "Lizzard", "orange".
###   Example of folded string:
###   > Art thou not Romeo,
###     and a Montague?

###.  =======
###'  LOGGING

##
## loglevel: Verbosity of log files generated by ejabberd.
## 0: No ejabberd log at all (not recommended)
## 1: Critical
## 2: Error
## 3: Warning
## 4: Info
## 5: Debug
##
loglevel: 4

##
## rotation: Describe how to rotate logs. Either size and/or date can trigger
## log rotation. Setting count to N keeps N rotated logs. Setting count to 0
## does not disable rotation, it instead rotates the file and keeps no previous
## versions around. Setting size to X rotate log when it reaches X bytes.
## To disable rotation set the size to 0 and the date to ""
## Date syntax is taken from the syntax newsyslog uses in newsyslog.conf.
## Some examples:
##  $D0     rotate every night at midnight
##  $D23    rotate every day at 23:00 hr
##  $W0D23  rotate every week on Sunday at 23:00 hr
##  $W5D16  rotate every week on Friday at 16:00 hr
##  $M1D0   rotate on the first day of every month at midnight
##  $M5D6   rotate on every 5th day of the month at 6:00 hr
##
log_rotate_size: 10485760
log_rotate_date: ""
log_rotate_count: 1

##
## overload protection: If you want to limit the number of messages per second
## allowed from error_logger, which is a good idea if you want to avoid a flood
## of messages when system is overloaded, you can set a limit.
## 100 is ejabberd's default.
log_rate_limit: 100

##
## watchdog_admins: Only useful for developers: if an ejabberd process
## consumes a lot of memory, send live notifications to these XMPP
## accounts.
##
## watchdog_admins:
##   - "admin@jabber.local"

###.  ===============
###'  NODE PARAMETERS

##
## net_ticktime: Specifies net_kernel tick time in seconds. This options must have
## identical value on all nodes, and in most cases shouldn't be changed at all from
## default value.
##
## net_ticktime: 60

###.  ================
###'  SERVED HOSTNAMES

##
## hosts: Domains served by ejabberd.
## You can define one or several, for example:
## hosts: 
##   - "example.net"
##   - "example.com"
##   - "example.org"
##
hosts:
  - "jabber.local"

##
## route_subdomains: Delegate subdomains to other XMPP servers.
## For example, if this ejabberd serves example.org and you want
## to allow communication with an XMPP server called im.example.org.
##
## route_subdomains: s2s

###.  ===============
###'  LISTENING PORTS

##
## listen: The ports ejabberd will listen on, which service each is handled
## by and what options to start it with.
##
listen: 
  - 
    port: 5222
    module: ejabberd_c2s
    certfile: "/home/administrador/ejabberd/conf/server.pem"
    starttls: true
    ## To enforce TLS encryption for client connections,
    ## use this instead of the "starttls" option:
    ## starttls_required: true
    ##
    ## Custom OpenSSL options
    ##
    protocol_options:
      - "no_sslv3"
    ##   - "no_tlsv1"
    max_stanza_size: 65536
    shaper: c2s_shaper
    access: c2s
  - 
    port: 5269
    module: ejabberd_s2s_in
    max_stanza_size: 131072
    shaper: s2s_shaper
  ##
  ## ejabberd_service: Interact with external components (transports, ...)
  ##
  ## - 
  ##   port: 8888
  ##   module: ejabberd_service
  ##   access: all
  ##   shaper_rule: fast
  ##   ip: "127.0.0.1"
  ##   hosts:
  ##     "icq.example.org":
  ##       password: "secret"
  ##     "sms.example.org":
  ##       password: "secret"

  ##
  ## ejabberd_stun: Handles STUN Binding requests
  ##
  ## - 
  ##   port: 3478
  ##   transport: udp
  ##   module: ejabberd_stun

  ##
  ## To handle XML-RPC requests that provide admin credentials:
  ##
  ## - 
  ##   port: 4560
  ##   module: ejabberd_xmlrpc
  ##   maxsessions: 10
  ##   timeout: 5000
  ##   access_commands:
  ##     admin:
  ##       commands: all
  ##       options: []
  - 
    port: 5280
    module: ejabberd_http
    request_handlers:
      "/websocket": ejabberd_http_ws
    ##  "/pub/archive": mod_http_fileserver
    web_admin: true
    http_bind: true
    register: true
    captcha: false

###.  ==================
###'  S2S GLOBAL OPTIONS

##
## s2s_use_starttls: Enable STARTTLS + Dialback for S2S connections.
## Allowed values are: false optional required required_trusted
## You must specify a certificate file.
##
## s2s_use_starttls: optional

##
## s2s_certfile: Specify a certificate file.
##
## s2s_certfile: "/home/administrador/ejabberd/conf/server.pem"

## Custom OpenSSL options
##
## s2s_protocol_options:
##   - "no_sslv3"
##   - "no_tlsv1"

##
## domain_certfile: Specify a different certificate for each served hostname.
##
## host_config:
##   "example.org":
##     domain_certfile: "/home/administrador/ejabberd/conf/example_org.pem"
##   "example.com":
##     domain_certfile: "/home/administrador/ejabberd/conf/example_com.pem"

##
## S2S whitelist or blacklist
##
## Default s2s policy for undefined hosts.
##
## s2s_access: s2s

##
## Outgoing S2S options
##
## Preferred address families (which to try first) and connect timeout
## in milliseconds.
##
## outgoing_s2s_families:
##   - ipv4
##   - ipv6
## outgoing_s2s_timeout: 10000

###.  ==============
###'  AUTHENTICATION

##
## auth_method: Method used to authenticate the users.
## The default method is the internal.
## If you want to use a different method,
## comment this line and enable the correct ones.
##
auth_method: internal

##
## Store the plain passwords or hashed for SCRAM:
## auth_password_format: plain
## auth_password_format: scram
##
## Define the FQDN if ejabberd doesn't detect it:
## fqdn: "server3.example.com"

##
## Authentication using external script
## Make sure the script is executable by ejabberd.
##
## auth_method: external
## extauth_program: "/path/to/authentication/script"

##
## Authentication using ODBC
## Remember to setup a database in the next section.
##
## auth_method: odbc

##
## Authentication using PAM
##
## auth_method: pam
## pam_service: "pamservicename"

##
## Authentication using LDAP
##
## auth_method: ldap
##
## List of LDAP servers:
## ldap_servers:
##   - "localhost"
##
## Encryption of connection to LDAP servers:
## ldap_encrypt: none
## ldap_encrypt: tls
##
## Port to connect to on LDAP servers:
## ldap_port: 389
## ldap_port: 636
##
## LDAP manager:
## ldap_rootdn: "dc=example,dc=com"
##
## Password of LDAP manager:
## ldap_password: "******"
##
## Search base of LDAP directory:
## ldap_base: "dc=example,dc=com"
##
## LDAP attribute that holds user ID:
## ldap_uids:
##   - "mail": "%u@mail.example.org"
##
## LDAP filter:
## ldap_filter: "(objectClass=shadowAccount)"

##
## Anonymous login support:
##   auth_method: anonymous
##   anonymous_protocol: sasl_anon | login_anon | both
##   allow_multiple_connections: true | false
##
## host_config:
##   "public.example.org":
##     auth_method: anonymous
##     allow_multiple_connections: false
##     anonymous_protocol: sasl_anon
##
## To use both anonymous and internal authentication:
##
## host_config:
##   "public.example.org":
##     auth_method:
##       - internal
##       - anonymous

###.  ==============
###'  DATABASE SETUP

## ejabberd by default uses the internal Mnesia database,
## so you do not necessarily need this section.
## This section provides configuration examples in case
## you want to use other database backends.
## Please consult the ejabberd Guide for details on database creation.


##   MySQL server:

odbc_type: mysql
odbc_server: "localhost"
odbc_database: "chat"
odbc_username: "admin"
odbc_password: "admin"
  
## If you want to specify the port:
odbc_port: 3306

##
## PostgreSQL server:
##
## odbc_type: pgsql
## odbc_server: "server"
## odbc_database: "database"
## odbc_username: "username"
## odbc_password: "password"
##
## If you want to specify the port:
## odbc_port: 1234
##
## If you use PostgreSQL, have a large database, and need a
## faster but inexact replacement for "select count(*) from users"
##
## pgsql_users_number_estimate: true

##
## SQLite:
##
## odbc_type: sqlite
## odbc_database: "/home/administrador/ejabberd/database/ejabberd.db"

##
## ODBC compatible or MSSQL server:
##
## odbc_type: odbc
## odbc_server: "DSN=ejabberd;UID=ejabberd;PWD=ejabberd"

##
## Number of connections to open to the database for each virtual host
##
## odbc_pool_size: 10

##
## Interval to make a dummy SQL request to keep the connections to the
## database alive. Specify in seconds: for example 28800 means 8 hours
##
## odbc_keepalive_interval: undefined

###.  ===============
###'  TRAFFIC SHAPERS

shaper:
  ##
  ## The "normal" shaper limits traffic speed to 1000 B/s
  ##
  normal: 1000

  ##
  ## The "fast" shaper limits traffic speed to 50000 B/s
  ##
  fast: 50000

##
## This option specifies the maximum number of elements in the queue
## of the FSM. Refer to the documentation for details.
##
max_fsm_queue: 1000

###.   ====================
###'   ACCESS CONTROL LISTS
acl:
  ##
  ## The 'admin' ACL grants administrative privileges to XMPP accounts.
  ## You can put here as many accounts as you want.
  ##
  admin:
    user:
      - "admin": "jabber.local"

  ##
  ## Blocked users
  ##
  ## blocked:
  ##   user:
  ##     - "baduser": "example.org"
  ##     - "test"

  ## Local users: don't modify this.
  ##
  local: 
    user_regexp: ""

  ##
  ## More examples of ACLs
  ##
  ## jabberorg:
  ##   server:
  ##     - "jabber.org"
  ## aleksey:
  ##   user:
  ##     - "aleksey": "jabber.ru"
  ## test:
  ##   user_regexp: "^test"
  ##   user_glob: "test*"

  ##
  ## Loopback network
  ##
  loopback:
    ip:
      - "127.0.0.0/8"

  ##
  ## Bad XMPP servers
  ##
  ## bad_servers:
  ##   server:
  ##     - "xmpp.zombie.org"
  ##     - "xmpp.spam.com"

##
## Define specific ACLs in a virtual host.
##
## host_config:
##   "localhost":
##     acl:
##       admin:
##         user:
##           - "bob-local": "localhost"

###.  ============
###'  ACCESS RULES
access:
  ## Maximum number of simultaneous sessions allowed for a single user:
  max_user_sessions: 
    all: 10
  ## Maximum number of offline messages that users can have:
  max_user_offline_messages: 
    admin: 5000
    all: 1000
  ## This rule allows access only for local users:
  local: 
    local: allow
  ## Only non-blocked users can use c2s connections:
  c2s: 
    blocked: deny
    all: allow
  ## For C2S connections, all users except admins use the "normal" shaper
  c2s_shaper: 
    admin: none
    all: normal
  ## All S2S connections use the "fast" shaper
  s2s_shaper: 
    all: fast
  ## Only admins can send announcement messages:
  announce: 
    admin: allow
  ## Only admins can use the configuration interface:
  configure: 
    admin: allow
  ## Admins of this server are also admins of the MUC service:
  muc_admin: 
    admin: allow
  ## Only accounts of the local ejabberd server can create rooms:
  muc_create: 
    local: allow
  ## All users are allowed to use the MUC service:
  muc: 
    all: allow
  ## Only accounts on the local ejabberd server can create Pubsub nodes:
  pubsub_createnode: 
    local: allow
  ## In-band registration allows registration of any possible username.
  ## To disable in-band registration, replace 'allow' with 'deny'.
  register: 
    all: allow
  ## Only allow to register from localhost
  trusted_network: 
    loopback: allow
  ## Do not establish S2S connections with bad servers
  ## s2s: 
  ##   bad_servers: deny
  ##   all: allow

## By default the frequency of account registrations from the same IP
## is limited to 1 account every 10 minutes. To disable, specify: infinity
## registration_timeout: 600
  
##
## Define specific Access Rules in a virtual host.
##
## host_config:
##   "localhost":
##     access:
##       c2s:
##         admin: allow
##         all: deny
##       register:
##         all: deny

###.  ================
###'  DEFAULT LANGUAGE

##
## language: Default language used for server messages.
##
language: "en"

##
## Set a different default language in a virtual host.
##
## host_config:
##   "localhost":
##     language: "ru"

###.  =======
###'  CAPTCHA

##
## Full path to a script that generates the image.
##
## captcha_cmd: "/home/administrador/ejabberd/lib/ejabberd-16.04/priv/bin/captcha.sh"

##
## Host for the URL and port where ejabberd listens for CAPTCHA requests.
##
## captcha_host: "jabber.local:5280"

##
## Limit CAPTCHA calls per minute for JID/IP to avoid DoS.
##
## captcha_limit: 5

###.  =======
###'  MODULES

##
## Modules enabled in all ejabberd virtual hosts.
##
modules: 
  mod_adhoc: {}
  mod_admin_extra: {}
  mod_announce: # recommends mod_adhoc
    access: announce
  mod_blocking: {} # requires mod_privacy
  mod_caps: {}
  mod_carboncopy: {}
  mod_client_state: {}
  mod_configure: {} # requires mod_adhoc
  mod_disco: {}
  ## mod_echo: {}
  ## mod_irc: {}
  mod_http_bind: {}
  ## mod_http_fileserver:
  ##   docroot: "/var/www"
  ##   accesslog: "/home/administrador/ejabberd/logs/access.log"
  mod_last: {}
  mod_mam:
    db_type: odbc
  mod_muc: 
    ## host: "conference.@HOST@"
    access: muc
    access_create: muc_create
    access_persistent: muc_create
    access_admin: muc_admin
  mod_muc_admin: {}
  ## mod_muc_log: {}
  ## mod_multicast: {}
  mod_offline_odbc: 
    access_max_user_messages: max_user_offline_messages
  mod_ping: {}
  ## mod_pres_counter:
  ##   count: 5
  ##   interval: 60
  mod_privacy: {}
  mod_private: {}
  ## mod_proxy65: {}
  mod_pubsub: 
    access_createnode: pubsub_createnode
    ## reduces resource comsumption, but XEP incompliant
    ignore_pep_from_offline: true
    ## XEP compliant, but increases resource comsumption
    ## ignore_pep_from_offline: false
    last_item_cache: false
    plugins: 
      - "flat"
      - "hometree"
      - "pep" # pep requires mod_caps
  mod_register: 
    ##
    ## Protect In-Band account registrations with CAPTCHA.
    ##
    ## captcha_protected: true

    ##
    ## Set the minimum informational entropy for passwords.
    ##
    ## password_strength: 32

    ##
    ## After successful registration, the user receives
    ## a message with this subject and body.
    ##
    welcome_message: 
      subject: "Welcome!"
      body: |-
        Hi.
        Welcome to this XMPP server.

    ##
    ## When a user registers, send a notification to
    ## these XMPP accounts.
    ##
    ## registration_watchers:
    ##   - "admin1@example.org"

    ##
    ## Only clients in the server machine can register accounts
    ##
    ip_access: trusted_network

    ##
    ## Local c2s or remote s2s users cannot register accounts
    ##
    ## access_from: register

    access: register
  mod_roster_odbc: {}
  mod_shared_roster: {}
  ## mod_stats: {}
  ## mod_time: {}
  mod_vcard: {}
  mod_version: {}

##
## Enable modules with custom options in a specific virtual host
##
## host_config:
##   "localhost":
##     modules:
##       mod_echo:
##         host: "mirror.localhost"

##
## Enable modules management via ejabberdctl for installation and
## uninstallation of public/private contributed modules
## (enabled by default)
##

allow_contrib_modules: true

###.
###'
### Local Variables:
### mode: yaml
### End:
### vim: set filetype=yaml tabstop=8 foldmarker=###',###. foldmethod=marker:
```

**Latest entries of ejabberd.log**

```
2016-05-06 10:26:31.546 [info] <0.7.0> Application lager started on node ejabberd@localhost
2016-05-06 10:26:31.576 [info] <0.7.0> Application crypto started on node ejabberd@localhost
2016-05-06 10:26:31.606 [info] <0.7.0> Application sasl started on node ejabberd@localhost
2016-05-06 10:26:31.631 [info] <0.7.0> Application asn1 started on node ejabberd@localhost
2016-05-06 10:26:31.632 [info] <0.7.0> Application public_key started on node ejabberd@localhost
2016-05-06 10:26:31.654 [info] <0.7.0> Application ssl started on node ejabberd@localhost
2016-05-06 10:26:31.679 [info] <0.7.0> Application fast_yaml started on node ejabberd@localhost
2016-05-06 10:26:31.711 [info] <0.7.0> Application fast_tls started on node ejabberd@localhost
2016-05-06 10:26:31.736 [info] <0.7.0> Application fast_xml started on node ejabberd@localhost
2016-05-06 10:26:31.746 [info] <0.7.0> Application stringprep started on node ejabberd@localhost
2016-05-06 10:26:31.766 [info] <0.7.0> Application cache_tab started on node ejabberd@localhost
2016-05-06 10:26:32.099 [info] <0.7.0> Application mnesia started on node ejabberd@localhost
2016-05-06 10:26:33.919 [info] <0.7.0> Application inets started on node ejabberd@localhost
2016-05-06 10:26:34.287 [warning] <0.39.0>@ejabberd_config:emit_deprecation_warning:1294 Module mod_roster_odbc is deprecated, use mod_roster with 'db_type: sql' instead
2016-05-06 10:26:35.975 [info] <0.7.0> Application p1_mysql started on node ejabberd@localhost
2016-05-06 10:26:36.006 [info] <0.39.0>@cyrsasl_digest:start:60 FQDN used to check DIGEST-MD5 SASL authentication: oficina24
2016-05-06 10:26:36.202 [info] <0.510.0>@ejabberd_listener:listen_tcp:189 Reusing listening port for {5222,{0,0,0,0},tcp}
2016-05-06 10:26:36.202 [info] <0.511.0>@ejabberd_listener:listen_tcp:189 Reusing listening port for {5269,{0,0,0,0},tcp}
2016-05-06 10:26:36.203 [info] <0.513.0>@ejabberd_listener:listen_tcp:189 Reusing listening port for {5280,{0,0,0,0},tcp}
2016-05-06 10:26:36.203 [info] <0.39.0>@ejabberd_app:start:76 ejabberd 16.04 is started in the node ejabberd@localhost
2016-05-06 10:26:36.203 [info] <0.7.0> Application ejabberd started on node ejabberd@localhost
```

I've executed mysql.sql script on phpmyadmin and the database is correctly setted up.

The problem is that I'm not able to link ejabberd with mysql because when I register a user with ejabberd web admin it doesn't store it in sql database.
Since I can't store the user I'm not able to check for the messaging storage neither.

Am I missing something?

Regards!

**EDIT:**

user on **.yml**

```
admin:
    user:
      - "admin": "jabber.local"
      - "admin": "localhost"
```

**ejabberd.log**

```
2016-05-06 11:28:40.055 [warning] <0.525.0>@ejabberd_web_admin:process:239 Access of <<"admin@localhost">> from <<"127.0.0.1">> failed with error: <<"inexistent-account">>
2016-05-06 11:28:43.813 [error] <0.525.0>@ejabberd_sql:check_error:991 SQL query 'Q9525209' at {sql_queries,145} failed: <<"Unknown Host">>
2016-05-06 11:28:43.813 [error] <0.525.0>@ejabberd_sql:check_error:991 SQL query 'Q9525209' at {sql_queries,145} failed: <<"Unknown Host">>
2016-05-06 11:28:43.813 [error] <0.525.0>@ejabberd_auth:is_user_exists:316 The authentication module ejabberd_auth_sql returned an error
when checking user <<"admin">> in server <<"localhost">>
Error message: <<"Unknown Host">>
```

Comment: provide detailed configration of ejabberd.yml file the above configuration seems ok and also provide ejabberd  log.

Comment: @SunilSingh I've edited the question. Hope you can help me!

Comment: ejabberd could not connect with mysql verify username,password , database name and mysql listening port  are correct ?. replace auth_method: internal with  auth_method: odbc in configuration file.

Comment: @SunilSingh  I've reedited ejabberd.log after changing some things. I think now it's connected. The problem now would be registering users and saving them in the db. How can I do that?

Comment: you can register user using ejabberd command- ejabberdctl register username host password

Comment: you can also manual entry in users table ejabberd database (mysql). set this user as admin in ejabberd configuration file and then you can login in  web admin of ejabberd.

Comment: @SunilSingh I've entered an account on my db but what domain should I use in my ejabberd.yml file? I've used the one that i've been using lately but the ejabberd.log tells me  `2016-05-06 11:06:51.444 [warning] <0.521.0>@ejabberd_web_admin:process:239 Access of <<"admin">> from <<"192.168.1.108">> failed with error: <<"inexistent-account">>`

Comment: @SunilSingh I've edited the question again. My domain before wasn't localhost. It was jabber.local which is my 192.162.... ip. Maybe that's important info.

Comment: user username as admin@jabber.local

Comment: @SunilSingh I've tried all the combinations but it keeps saying inexisting-account.. I'm a little bit lost right now... I have three questions. What user should the sql db have? what username and domain has the .yml has to have? and what is the domain:port/(user) that I have to connect to access the web admin?

Comment: In db username- "admin" only . in ejabberd.yml  -- "admin": "your host name during installation time"    example  - - "admin": "jabber.local"  and domain name your local ip address or http://localhost:5280/admin

Comment: @SunilSingh ok, sql db and ejabberd are finally linked. The users register successfully. Now the problem is about saving the messages. What field should store the messages and how should I do it. Cause the mod_mam is enabled but it doesn't seem to be working. Thanks.

Comment: enable mod_offline for example-mod_offline: 
    access_max_user_messages: max_user_offline_messages
    db_type: odbc        in ejabberd.yml and your offline message will stored in "spool" table in mysql.

Comment: @SunilSingh Ok that's perfect, it's working. Thank you very much!. Now the only thing left is that when you refresh the page the messages dissappear. Is there any way to keep the conversation??

Comment: @SunilSingh I can store the offline messages and send them when the other user is online. But how can I save the full conversation?

Comment: if you want save full conversion  read here -https://www.ejabberd.im/contributions

Comment: I have the same problem with the database
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38808877/ejabberd-16-06-mysql-5-5-50-message-history-is-not-saved
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an issue with your database configuration. ejabberd cannot connect to it, as stated in error message:

```
Failed connecting to "localhost":3306 : {error,econnrefused}
```

You are saying that it stores users in SQL db, but you are likely mistaken as ejabberd cannot connect to the database.

I think it should be actually storing data in Mnesia. This is confirmed by your config (auth_method: internal)

Comment: I have internal auth now because i wasn't able to register users with odbc auth (which I believe it would be the right conf for my purpose). Thing is..  Can I register users with ejabberd web admin and those being stored in sql with odbc auth?

Comment: Web admin only work with internal database. Truth is that serious admin use ejabberdctl command line for ejabberd administration.

Comment: I saw that but since I updated my ejabberd from 14.07 to 16.04 I don't have ejabberdctl command anymore. Terminal tells me to apt-get install ejabberd but we are afraid it might install an old version of ejabberd over ours

Comment: How did you install ejabberd ? ejabberdctl should be available in 16.04 as well. Your installation seems broken.

Comment: I purged my old version (installed with apt-get install) and then I installed the latest version from ejabberd web just following the steps

Comment: So you should have ejabberdctl

Comment: Yeah, I should... Problem is I don't. However I managed to insert an admin through db and now it's working. The messages are being saved  in the spool table now I need to know how retrieve them when reconnecting.

Comment: I mean, the offline messages are shown when the other user connects. The problem is to save the conversation in the db to show it whenever the user reconnects. Right now when reconnecting the conversation is lost.